# How does work function overload resolving with variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-functions

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1

#define IDS_MYSTR 123

void FnVariadic(const long nIDS, ...)
{
  std::cout << "WITHOUT option IDS" << std::endl;
}

void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const long nIDS, ...)
{
  std::cout << "WITH option IDS" << std::endl;
}

void FnVariadic(const char *pStr, ...)
{
  std::cout << "WITHOUT option STR" << std::endl;
}

void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const char *pStr, ...)
{
  std::cout << "WITH option STR" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  FnVariadic(FALSE, IDS_MYSTR, "abc");
  //FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, FALSE, "abc"); //???
  FnVariadic(TRUE, IDS_MYSTR, "abc");
  FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, TRUE, "abc");    //???

  FnVariadic(FALSE, "abc%s", "abc");
  //FnVariadic("abc%d%s", FALSE, "abc");
  FnVariadic(TRUE, "abc%s", "abc");
  //FnVariadic("abc%d%s", TRUE, "abc");

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain how does work here funtion overload resolving?
 The surprising thing is there;

```
  //FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, FALSE, "abc"); //???
  FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, TRUE, "abc");    //???
```

Second one compiles but not the first one.

(Commented lines mean does not compile.)

I'm using VS2017, and it seems;

First 3 calls uses `void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const long nIDS, ...)` and last 2 calls uses `void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const char *pStr, ...)`

It is also intresting there. What i expected is that the overloads without boolean parameter should be called.

Comment: Your problem is that FALSE being #define'd as 0 equals the null pointer constant, and thus the resolution is ambiguous between the long and const char* overload. This situation only exist for the literal constant 0, and this was partly why nullptr was designed (but as you can see, the problem still exists in the language).

Comment: Why do you need to use a macro to define `true` and `false`? These boolean constants were built into the language ages ago.

Comment: @AndyG we are using mfc/atl. There were no boolean true/false as those codes have been written. And those defines have been used. But i'm trying to understand overload resolving. Not looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ellipses are the last resort in overload resolution, if there is a better match then the function call will be resolved to that match.  Your function calls (non commented) all involve an integer literal as the first argument.  And since your macros, when replaced are all viable candidates for conversions to `bool`, you have two candidates

```
void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const long nIDS, ...)
void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const char *pStr, ...)
```

And then in the first three you provide integer literals as the second argument.  So the first overload between the two above is called.  And in the last 2 you provide string literals (which are decayable to `const char*`) and therefore the second overload is called between the two above.

---

As to why the commented lines do not compile

```
// FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, FALSE, "abc"); //???
```

This does not compile because the second argument is ambiguous, a `0` has special meaning unfortunately, it can resolve to both a `const char*` as well as a `const long`

```
// FnVariadic("abc%d%s", FALSE, "abc");
```

Same for this one, the `FALSE` is ambiguous

```
// FnVariadic("abc%d%s", TRUE, "abc");
```

Here the conversion to `bool` for `"abc%d%s"` and the matching of `"abc"` to the ellipses has the same precedence, and therefore it is ambiguous.

---

For your reference, it is almost always better to use compile time variadic templates over C style variadics.

Comment: Is it possible to deactivate this implicit 0 -> ptr cast? I mean can it be prevented that 0 as ptr represented? With a compiler option maybe?

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz No. GCC has a warning for it, but the language breaks without this conversion in many cases. If you're interested in a solution, it is quite easy to refactor your code so it works correctly (for instance, using SFINAE).

Answer (score 1):

As @Shaggi already pointed out. Acc to standard,

> Before nullptr was introduced, zero (0) was used as a notation for the
>   null pointer. For example:
>
> ```
> int* x = 0; // x gets the value nullptr
> ```
>
> No object is allocated with the address 0, and 0 (the all-zeros bit
>   pattern) is the most common representation of nullptr. Zero (0) is an
>   int. However, the standard conversions (§10.5.2.3) allow 0 to be used
>   as a constant of pointer or pointer-to-member type

```
FnVariadic(IDS_MYSTR, FALSE, "abc"); 
                        ^~~~const char * OR const long. This is ambiguous.
```

as you have both

```
void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const long nIDS, ...)
void FnVariadic(const bool bOption, const char *pStr, ...)
```